How to use multiprocessing locks in joblib?
I want to use a lock in joblib using backend multiprocessing or loky. It seems to be simple enough with using standard lib's multiprocessing, but with joblib it's not: It complains that the lock is not picklable:
#!Python
from multiprocessing import Process, Lock
from joblib import Parallel, delayed


def f(l, i):
    l.acquire()
    try:
        print('hello world', i)
    finally:
        l.release()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lock = Lock()

    for num in range(10):
        Process(target=f, args=(lock, num)).start()

    Parallel(n_jobs=2)(delayed(f)(lock, i) for i in range(10, 20))

So far I've googled, read the documentation, searched the joblib GitHub project, and tried variants like implementing the lock as a global variable, but to no avail.

While it is possible that there is a joblib specific solution, it is likely to be a duplicate of this. In short, you need to use multiprocessing.Manager().Lock().

This does indeed work, thanks.

@ken maybe you should put your comment as answer - with some example code. OR we can vote it as duplicate to question from your link.

Does this answer your question? Python sharing a lock between processes

TBH I needed the added information that this applies to joblib parallelization too - hadn't thought of googling for general pool multi-processing. But since this answer will stay even if marked as duplicate, I don't mind either way.
